# How to fill a Map<String, List<String>> from a text file ? -Difficulites dynamically naming each List

Tags: java, list, hashmap

Here is the text file. K: represents a key and V: represents the values in the List I want to enter. ie : Strawberry , Apricot and Peach make up the List at Key Class A of the Map.

```
K: Class A//
V: Strawberry//
V: Apricot//
V: Peach//
K: Class B//
V: Chocolate//
K: Class C//
V: Creme de menthe//
V: Irish coffee//
```

The program here assigns the Keys correctly but adds every Value in the file to the List instead of just the ones I want.

```
//FillHM.java 

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;          

public class FillHM  {

   public static void main (String[] args)  {
     Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
     Scanner sc1 = null;

     try  {  
        sc1 = new Scanner(new File("/home/craig/Desktop/mytext.txt"));
     }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

     List<String>values = new ArrayList<>();
     String s = " ";
     String key = " ";

     while (sc1.hasNextLine())  {
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(sc1.nextLine());
            sc2.useDelimiter("//");

            while(sc2.hasNext())  {
                s = sc2.next();      
                if  (s.startsWith("K:"))  {
                    key = s;
                }       
                if (s.startsWith("V:"))  {
                    values.add(s);   
                }
                map.put(key, values);
            } //end while
     }  //end while 
     System.out.println(map);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just call `values.clear()` at the top of the `while` loop.

Comment: He needs to create a new list, not clear the existing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you detect a new key, create a new list:

```
if (s.startsWith("K:"))  {
    key = s;
    values = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

If you don't do this, every key will be mapped to the *same* list. You want each key mapped to *its own* list.

Comment: 0.o as easy as that. Many Thanks Bohemian ;D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is , you can't use values.clear() , because it will clear values of all keys.
So below is the solution .

```
  if (s.startsWith("K:")) {
          values = new ArrayList<>();
          key = s;       
  }
```

Just change this `if`.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that your values list is never get clear when the key get changed.**
SO make sure to clear the list when you add key and values to the map

```
 if  (s.startsWith("K:"))  {
     key = s; 
     values.clear();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code will work for you buddy. **values.clear()** **will not resolve** the issue.

```
     Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
     Scanner sc1 = null;

     try  {  
        sc1 = new Scanner(new File("/home/craig/Desktop/mytext.txt"));
     }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

     String s = "";
     String key = "";
     List<String>values=new ArrayList<>();

     while (sc1.hasNextLine())  {
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(sc1.nextLine());
            sc2.useDelimiter("//");

                s = sc2.next();      
                if  (s.startsWith("K:"))  {
                    if(values.size()!=0){
                        map.put(key, values);
                        //System.out.println(map);
                    }
                    key = s;
                    values=new ArrayList<>();
                }       
                else if (s.startsWith("V:"))  {
                    values.add(s);   
                }


     } 
     map.put(key, values);
     System.out.println(map);
```